# Is Hulu's version of Trigun edited?

Tags: anime, production, trigun

Recently, I've been watching *Trigun* on Hulu. It seems to have the occasional awkward cut, and the narrative seems to noticeably jump sometimes. I don't know if this is due to editing for content or other reasons, or if it's just how the show is.

Besides being dubbed, is Hulu's version different from the original Japanese version in any way?

The Hulu version is currently free, so anyone in America can compare it to another version if they want to.

---

[Yes, I am aware of the Anime and Manga Stack Exchange. However, as *Trigun* is a science fiction work, it is therefore [also on-topic here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/627/51226).]

---

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about this series. - Is it possible that they've taken the dubbed source from somewhere and edited out the advert breaks?

Comment: @Valorum That's possible, but they would be strange places to have ads.

Comment: Fair enough. American shows have ads every fourteen seconds so it's often hard to judge.

Comment: I haven't seen Trigun on Hulu, but I kind of doubt it.  Editing takes more work.  The last episode of Trigun is kind of abrupt, due to it diverging from the manga, which wasn't even complete at the time.

Comment: I can tell you that the narrative on *Trigun* jumps a lot, but I can't verify for Hulu specifically.

Comment: @Axelrod If you live in America, you can check out the Hulu version for free, if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version on Hulu does not seem to be cut for content, but it does have some minor alterations to its opening animation.

*Trigun* was originally dubbed and released by Pioneer pretty much intact. The one exception: in the Japanese version, the opening animation would show different characters, while the original Pioneer release used the animation from the first episode for every episode, so the Episode 1 villain keeps appearing long after he's gone from the show. From [the Anime News Network entry on *Trigun*](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=88):

> The initial region 1 version of Trigun released by Pioneer/Geneon (original Pioneer and Geneon Signature Series) did not include unique opening animations for each episode as did the Japanese release of the series. The first episode's opening animation was used for the entire series in the US domestic release, while normally, the opening animation highligted characters present in the particular episode that was playing. Geneon's latest release of Trigun (Limited Collector's Sets 1 & 2) has restored each unique opening animation to its original state.

Geneon later folded and lost the license to *Trigun*. It was picked up by Funimation, whose release is the one playing on Hulu. From [a review of the Funimation DVD release](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/review/trigun/dvd-the-complete-series) on Anime News Network:

> Funimation's boxed set rerelease is apparently taken from the original Geneon/Pioneer releases rather than the later Limited Collector's Set releases, so fans looking for the openers as they originally played in the Japanese broadcast – i.e. with slight adjustments to the animation each time to reflect characters featured in that episode – will be disappointed. Instead, Episode 1's opener repeats throughout.

I watched bits of a few episodes to confirm that the dub is the same, and that the same opening animation seems to appear in Episodes 1 and 2.

*Trigun* was also shown on Cartoon Network, where it was edited for content. At the time, Anime News Network had a feature called [The Edit List](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/edit-list/2003/05#articles) where they tracked cuts to anime airing on TV. The *Trigun* episodes are spread across April 2003 and May 2003. I checked on a few of these scenes and confirmed that the uncut version is what's on Hulu. For example, from [Episode 1](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/edit-list/2003-04-03/trigun-ep-1-and-2):

> 2) Boss's "You asshole! What the hell do you thing [sic] you're aiming at?" changed to "What the hell do you think you're aiming at?"

This happens around the 13:15 mark in Episode 1, and the Boss does indeed say "You asshole!".

---

It's possible that Funimation cut the series when they did their DVD release, but it seems unlikely, especially for a show like *Trigun* that attracts an older audience. The choppiness probably comes from the fact the *Trigun* is not an amazingly well directed show. The art direction of the show was mediocre even at the time it was released and has aged very poorly compared to shows like *Cowboy Bebop* and *Evangelion*. I remember scene transitions and camera changes often feeling abrupt. The writing also has its flaws, mostly from the usual cause of trying to cram too much manga story into too little anime. That's probably enough to account for that disjointed feeling.

Answer (score 3):

Most hardcore anime fans typically abhor dubbed versions (especially if set in Japan). But I've not found anyone railing against the dub of Trigun. Indeed, [many are recommending the dub](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/2000121-anime-and-manga-other-titles/65617994). This is probably the same dub they showed on Cartoon Network so there's been plenty of time to rant about it.

Yes, the story does jump around a lot (especially in the beginning). I do promise it becomes more coherent as time goes along. The payoff at the end is definitely worth it.

Comment: Agreed in full, though I think you need an example to seal the deal.

Comment: @Axelrod I wish I had found one. Nobody really has any good comparisons out there. Probably because the Japanese version was not as popular as the dub.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the commercial transitions, Trigun only had one commercial transition per episode, which Adult Swim originally did as well, so the awkward cuts on Hulu are probably because those idiots are cutting things from the original episodes, since I've been noticing they do those awkward transitions sometimes more than once per episode.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any examples of content that has been cut, or any evidence (e.g. shortened run-times, etc.) that Hulu has been cutting content?